# SharePoint SecureStoreProvider not found

Tags: visual-studio, sharepoint, dll, sharepoint-2019

I am developing a `WebPart` in Visual Studio (using `.ascx`) for SharePoint Server 2019 Standard and need to access the Secure Store Service.  However, I cannot locate the `Microsoft.Office.SecureStoreService.Server.dll` which contains the `SecureStoreProvider` class.

I've searched the entire machine using PowerShell scripts without success.

I found a reference to this DLL in the [March 8, 2022, update for SharePoint Server 2019 (KB5002163)](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/topic/march-8-2022-update-for-sharepoint-server-2019-kb5002163-9a71a573-2367-4e3c-b251-001b0426828e), but this didn't lead anywhere as my installation is fully patched (October 2023 at the time of writing).

The only similar DLL I found is `Microsoft.Office.SecureStoreService.Server.Security.dll`, but it lacks the necessary `SecureStoreProvider` class.

Any suggestions on accessing `SecureStoreProvider` for my WebPart would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the DLL `Microsoft.Office.SecureStoreService.dll` in the GAC of any SharePoint Server part of your SharePoint farm:

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.Office.SecureStoreService
```

You may be also interesting in the following assemblies:

```
C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.BusinessData.dll

C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.Office.SecureStoreService.Server.Security.dll
```

Sources (working for SP 2019 as well) :

- [Microsoft.Office.SecureStoreService.dll not found](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/114899/microsoft-office-securestoreservice-dll-not-found)
- [SecureStoreService dll for SharePoint 2013](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/59361/securestoreservice-dll-for-sharepoint-2013)
- [Sharepoint 2013 Microsoft.Office.SecureStoreService.dll](https://raquelalineblog.wordpress.com/2013/05/09/sharepoint-2013-microsoft-office-securestoreservice-dll/)
- [How To Use SharePoint 2010 Secure Store As Single Sign-On Service For SAP Applications Using ERPConnect](http://www.parago.de/blog/2011/04/30/how-to-use-sharepoint-2010-secure-store-as-single-sign-on-service-for-sap-applications-using-erpconnect.html)

Comment: Thanks!  Been a looonng day and I was searching for `Microsoft.Office.SecureStoreService.Server` rather than the correct file.